# Update INI string using FindFirst

Tags: nsis

I'm trying to update an INI string that has something similar to `[Version]DisplayVersion=0.0.298` from finding a new directory in a folder. The current INI string, `0.0.298`, matches the current directory which looks like, `..\app-0.0.298`.

During runtime the application will sometimes update itself creating a new folder which might look like, `..\app-0.0.301`. What I want to do is find this directory and write its new version number to `[Version]DisplayVersion` to match the new updated version so it will look like this: `[Version]DisplayVersion=0.0.301`.

I have this so far which isn't working:

```nsis
FindFirst $0 $1 `${APPDIR}\app-*`
ReadEnvStr $2 BUILD # Set earlier in the script ($2 = 0.0.298)
StrCmp $1 "" +11
Push `$2.0`
Push `$1.0`
Call VersionCompare # http://nsis.sourceforge.net/VersionCompare
Pop $3
IntCmp $3 1 +4 +4 0
IfFileExists `${APPDIR}\app-$1\${APP}.exe` 0 +3
DeleteINIStr "${InfoINI}" "Version" "DisplayVersion"
WriteINIStr "${InfoINI}" "Version" "DisplayVersion" "$1"
FindNext $0 $1
Goto -10
FindClose $0
```

What am I missing here or is there a better way to be doing this?

Comment: What does not work? Directory enumeration? VersionCompare? Ini handling? And what is APPDIR and InfoINI defined as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you pass a wildcard to `FindFirst` the returned filename will still include the entire name and you end up comparing `0.0.298.0` to `app-0.0.298.0`.

```
Section "-Initialize example"
!define APP "MyApp"
!define APPDIR "$temp\Test"
!define InfoINI "$temp\Test\app.ini"
CreateDirectory "${APPDIR}\app-0.0.298"
WriteINIStr "${InfoINI}" "Version" "DisplayVersion" "0.0.298"
System::Call 'KERNEL32::SetEnvironmentVariable(t "BUILD", t "0.0.298")'
SectionEnd

!include LogicLib.nsh

Page Components
Page InstFiles

Section "Emulate a update"
CreateDirectory "${APPDIR}\app-0.0.301"
File "/oname=${APPDIR}\app-0.0.301\${APP}.exe" "${__FILE__}"
SectionEnd


Section "Test"
SectionIn RO
FindFirst $0 $1 `${APPDIR}\app-*`
ReadEnvStr $2 BUILD # Set earlier in the script ($2 = 0.0.298)
loop:
    StrCmp $1 "" done
    StrCpy $3 $1 4
    StrCmp $3 "app-" 0 trynext
    StrCpy $1 $1 "" 4 ; Remove "app-" prefix
    Push `$2.0`
    Push `$1.0`
    Call VersionCompare # http://nsis.sourceforge.net/VersionCompare
    Pop $3
    ${If} $3 > 1
        ${If} ${FileExists} "${APPDIR}\app-$1\${APP}.exe"
            # DeleteINIStr "${InfoINI}" "Version" "DisplayVersion" ; You don't have to delete before writing
            WriteINIStr "${InfoINI}" "Version" "DisplayVersion" "$1"
        ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}
    trynext:
        FindNext $0 $1
    Goto loop
done:
FindClose $0
SectionEnd
```

Tip: Using relative jumps makes the code harder to read (and modify), use labels and/or LogicLib.nsh

Comment: I should have known better but if I didn't, now I do. Thanks Anders. I usually need another set of eyes when I can't see something and your eyes always come through for me.